# Keeping an element fixed when browser is resized

Tags: css

I have a loader icon than appears next to a submit button. I'm having trouble getting the icon to stay in the same position relative to the submit button when the browser window is resized.  I hope someone can show me what I've got missing. Thanks.

```
 <span><button type="submit" name="btn-login" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-submit">Sign in</button>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw" id="loader"></i></span>
```

CSS

```
    #loader{
    position: absolute;
        top: 230px;
        right:440px;
}
```

Comment: as you already said in your question: the position of the loader has to be relative to the submit button. Instead of using `position: absolute` change it to `position: relative` and delete `top: 230px` and `right: 440px`. See [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s88L370t/).

Comment: Great, works perfectly, thanks.